# argparse taking int & string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

New to this so please excuse ignorance. Is it possible (if so, how can it be done) to take a command from a user that contains both numbers and letters? I want to take 3 arguments from a user when they enter something like "./test -selectport af15" (1st argument always one letter, 2nd always one letter, 3rd argument would be a 1 up to 3 digit number (1-999). Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The command line list contains strings, and by default `argparse` just assigns those strings to the `args` attributes.  So you'll get `args.selectport = 'af15'`.  You can split that string in what ever way you want - after parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think might be confusing you is the way the argparse docs tell you to treat an agrument as a type. When new to this it might make this seem more complex than it is. The other answer covers the how, but to explicitly answer your question:

Treat the whole thing as a string in argparse, parse out the three parts you want, and then make the last part an int yourself.

Should get you going:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-selectport', help='Will parse this string into a few items')

args = parser.parse_args()

first = args.selectport[0]
second = args.selectport[1]
last = int(args.selectport[2:])

print(f"{first} {second} {last}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this will do:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_input = sys.argv[2]
    first_letter = user_input[0]
    second_letter = user_input[1]
    third = user_input[2:]

    print(first_letter)
    print(second_letter)
    print(third)
```

Output:

```
python test.py -selectport af15
a
f
15
```

Of course, you need to handle special cases, possible user input errors etc on your own. Here I assume that the input is always given correctly. Start from here and elaborate.